# How can i expand the content through css?

Tags: html, css

I've tried different solutions that i've found here on stackoverflow, but they didn't work. I really don't know how to expand the content of the "Section" if the page is empty.

[My Project on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y8hrqj11/3/)

**HTML**

```
    <body>
        <header>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Option 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Option 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Option 4</a></li>
                <li id="home" class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <section>
            <h1 id="titolo">Main Title<br>Sub title</h1>
            <p>A lot of Content</p>
        </section>
      <footer>
        <p>Name Surname <br> <a href="mailto:youremail@mail.com">youremail@mail.com</a></p>
      </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
section {    
    margin: 44px 10%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.40); 
    padding:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to use flexbox which is much more simple (at least for me)

I modified your code in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smlrolland/L2jfss67/)

**HTML:**

```
<header>
   <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Option 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Option 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Option 4</a></li>
                <li id="home" class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>

<div class="wrapper">

  <section class="content">
    <h1 id="titolo">Main Title<br>Sub title</h1>
    <p>A lot of Content</p>
  </section>
</div> <!-- /wrapper -->

<footer>
  <p>Name Surname <br> <a href="mailto:youremail@mail.com">youremail@mail.com</a></p>
  </footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {display: flex; flex-direction: column;} /* IE fix */
body {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column; 
  min-height: 100vh; /* (compatible IE9+) */
}
.wrapper {
  display: block; /* IE fix */
  flex: 1 1 auto; 
   display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
nav {
  width: 15em;
}
.content {
  display: block; /* IE fix */
  flex: 1; 
}


body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

footer {
   height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#303030;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.99);
  color:white;
}

section {                       /*That's the part that i want to expand till the footer*/
    margin: 44px 10%;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.40);  
    padding:1px;
    overflow:hidden;

}


ul.menu {
  display:flex;
  font-size:110%;
  width:100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.99);
  list-style-type:none;
  background-color:#303030;
  color:white;
}

li a{
  float:left;
  padding: 13px 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color:#ff5722;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.80);
}

#home {
  position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  right:5px;
  }

li.active {
  background-color:#ff5722;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.99);
}

li a {
  display:block;
  color:white;
}


#titolo {
  border: 2px dashed #ff5722;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin:40px 40px 0px 40px;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a {
  color:#ff5722;
  text-decoration:none;
}

 span{
   color:#ff5722;
}

p {
  margin:0px 40px;
  display:block;
    }
```

You can learn about Flexbox in [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I 've found out a bug i guess, i can't understand why if i put in the html an image, the content of the section goes out and ruins everything https://jsfiddle.net/L2jfss67/2/

Comment: hmm I can't see what is your problem.. Your image is placed in your section, and on your jsfiddle, everything seems right in place. Tell me more about it

Comment: Ok sorry now i've seen that it was not enough text to see the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/L2jfss67/3/       http://imgur.com/QH0AdSG

Comment: ok this is a mozilla bug, add this "overflow:hidden;" in your section{} part

Comment: Ok perfect, everything goes in the right way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try height property.

```
section {    
margin: 44px 10%;
background-color:#ffffff;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.40); 
padding:1px;
height: auto;
/* or you can type manually*/
height: 200px (or any amount);
}
```

Comment: I've tried the `height:auto` but it doesn't work, while if i use `height: 500px` it work. But the problem is that the layout of the page will be ruined on another pc

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you exactly want but try this :

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
```

and add to your section tag :

```
section{
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Ok in this way the section has expanded, but too much. Infact it continues under the footer. I've just tried `height:calc(100% - 40px)` in the section, to reduce the page, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, understood, I post a new answer base on flexbox, check it out !